# Select query different level tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am having 4 tables. 2 of them are storing attribute datas (one is storing the name and code of every street, and the other one is linked to the first but add street number) as such :

```
CREATE TABLE public.adresse
(
  id_adress serial NOT NULL,
  nb_street character varying(10),
  id_street integer,
  CONSTRAINT prk_constraint_adresse PRIMARY KEY (id_adresse),
  CONSTRAINT fk_adresse_id_street FOREIGN KEY (id_street)
      REFERENCES public.street (id_street) MATCH SIMPLE
);

CREATE TABLE public.street
(
  id_street serial NOT NULL,
  name_street character varying(25),
  code_street character varying(25),
  CONSTRAINT prk_constraint_street PRIMARY KEY (id_street)
);
```

And the 2 other tables are relative to buildings, similar in the datas they store, but normalized to fit my database : one in which I want to insert datas coming from the other one copied from a csv. The one copied from the csv is like this

```
ID_BULDING;   CODE_STREET;    NB_STREET;      NAME_STREET;
34001;        0265;           44;             ALL DU TURET;
35001;        0265;           40;             ALL DU TURET;
38001;        0245;           12;             IMP DES SERINGATS;
39001;        0245;           28;             IMP DES SERINGATS;
```

And the one in which I want to insert :

```
CREATE TABLE public.built
(
  id_built serial NOT NULL,
  id_building character varying(40),
  id_adresse integer,
  CONSTRAINT prk_constraint_bal PRIMARY KEY (id_built),
  CONSTRAINT fk_bal_id_adresse FOREIGN KEY (id_adresse)
      REFERENCES public.adresse (id_adresse) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
)
```

The resulting tables would look like that :

```
ID_STREET;     NAME_STREET;           CODE_STREET;
1;             ALL DU TURET;          0265;
2;             IMP DES SERIGNATS      0245;

ID_ADRESSE;     NB_STREET;     ID_STREET;
1;              44;            1;
2;              40;            1;
3;              12;            2;
4;              28;            2;

ID_BULDING;     ID_ADRESSE;
34001;          1;
35001;          2;
38001;          3;
39001;          4;
```

So as you may see, there is in the inserted table a foreign key "id_adresse", and as you may imagine I would like to fill with the "id_adresse" fitting the criterias found in the table "adresse" accordingly with the table "voie". But I cannot figure out how to realize such a three level query. I tried some queries but I don't know how to declare the table "adresse" in the middle of the joins. For now I am stuck here :

```
INSERT INTO public.built(id_building,  id_adresse) 
SELECT id_building,  adresse.id_adresse 
FROM public.building
LEFT JOIN public.street 
   ON street.name_street=building.name_street 
  AND street.code_street=building.code_street;
```

I am quite new in the SQL world, working with PostgreSQL 9.5, and it is conceptually not really complex, so I am guessing there is an easy way to do that, I just haven't found it yet. Any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: you want to insert into 3 tables with one statement?.. if so use CTE and returning

Comment: You should really show some data for each table and the expected result. I am a french speaker and thus understand your table/columns names, but even with this I dont understand what you are trying to do. So I imagine that for non-french it should be worst

Comment: @ThomasG indeed, I made a first correction to hopefully clarify. I am making a second one to explain further the context.

Comment: Don't verbose too much. Just show some data and we will understand. SOurce tables/CSV + expected result

Comment: Is it better ? And thank you for taking the time to guide me into clarifying my post

Comment: @VaoTsun No, I use other statements to populate the street and adresse tables, it is really just the last step which is blocking me.

Comment: what's bad with your insert?.. error? unexpected result?

Comment: @VaoTsun Well, in this insert there is an error since no table "adresse" is being called, hence a problem for the second selected element "adresse.id_adresse"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voila ;)

```
INSERT INTO built(id_building,  id_adresse) 
SELECT B.id_building,  A.id_adresse 
FROM building B
LEFT JOIN street S ON S.code_street=B.code_street
LEFT JOIN adresse A ON  A.id_street=S.id_street AND A.nb_street = B.nb_street   ;
```

Tested here (without referential integrity) : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/89e81/1)

Comment: It does indeed work, however since I am not quite certain about the quality of the input data, I would like to check every attribute, and so add a constraint on the first join. And in that case I get some null result 50% of the time. Here it is : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1560b/1/0) (in fact my datas are much bigger than this little sample, and with more tables and more attributes. I then get systematic empty field in my "id_adress")

Comment: this is not a SQL issue, it's a data issue, there's nothing I can do

Comment: I thought so, an SQL issue would have seen an error message pop out. Maybe I should make another thread for this question, if you think so please tell me. But I thought adding some field references with some AND would have as effect the consideration of more fields to match. And if so I do not understand why, in the little example we have here, adding the constraint is causing a problem, especially since both statements are straightforwardly refering to the same table and the same tuples. Would you have any clue on that ?

Comment: Well, it was just mistake in the spelling of the name of the second street. It works now. Thank you very much for your help. :)